# CMake crossplatform read file to variable

Tags: windows, unix, cmake

I found something like this, but it doesn`t work. Can not understand, with what here initializes variable show_contents_prog - what mean 'cat' and 'type'
Can anybody help with correct way?

```
if (UNIX)
  set (show_contents_prog cat)
elseif (WIN32)
  set (show_contents_prog type)
endif (WIN32)

execute_process(COMMAND ${show_contents_prog} input.txt OUTPUT_VARIABLE file_contents)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is the CMake [`file(READ ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html) command:

```
file(READ input.txt file_contents)
```

As for [`cat`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1/cat/) on Unix systems or [`type`](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) on Windows, they basically print out the contents of the file(s) specified.